# Cutting of DNA strand

Tags: molecular-biology, dna-sequencing, restriction-enzymes

Would EcoRI cut the following sequence??

5'CTCGAGTTCGAG3'

3'GAGCTCAAGCTC5'

What is the logic of cutting? Please explain how restriction enzymes work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not cut it, because EcoRI recognizes the following palindromic sequence: GAATTC, and only if the whole sequence is present it will cut it at particular site. You can find these information for all restriction enzymes at sites of the providers, for example at New England Biolabs site https://www.neb.com , just enter the name of the enzyme you are interested in.